# Need help in getting http request in esp8266

Tags: http, post, arduino, get, esp8266

Hi beautiful community of ESP!

I am trying to send a http request from browser to the esp8266. Currently I have ESP8266WebServer running on the esp and listening to incoming http requests. I have a function which listens to request made by browser and activates a function example: if I type 'http://ipofesp/ledon' the ledon function will be called upon '/ledon' in the url.

The code I am using is:

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
ESP8266WebServer server;

void setup(){

server.on("/",[](){server.send(200,"text/plain","Hello World");});
server.on("/ledon",ledon);

server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

}

void loop() {
server.handleClient();
}

void ledon(){

digitalWrite(D5, LOW)

}

void handleNotFound(){

server.send(200,"text/plain","Wrong input");

}
```

This works file for me but now I am trying to send a http request from browser to the esp8266 with an http payload. How can I fetch the http payload in esp8266?

is there any built-in function in the server object?

Comment: `server.send()` is the way to send data back to client. Take a look at [PostServer](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/PostServer/PostServer.ino) example.

Comment: @hcheung I don't want to send data to client. client is sending http request with payload data. I want to fetch the data in esp8266

Comment: Is your client another esp8266? or simply a browser? For browser, you need to setup JavaScript [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) call from your browser to send the data back. You can take a look at one of my [project](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2019/11/build-an-esp32-web-server-and-ir-remote/) to see how to send data back.

Comment: On the server side, you need to setup the route/endpoint to handle the request and setup the appropriate html/javascript page at `/` route using  the same `server.send()`, which is why I suggest to take a look at PostServer example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a ''HTTP GET request''. For that you also need to define some PHP code to get the information from the webserver.

So you send some command to a PHP script, that command is processed on the webserver with results stored for a HTTP GET request from the ESP8266.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, you can send your payload in the form of URL parameters:

`http://ipofesp.com/led?pin=2&status=1`

Your web server can parse this URL and understand that the LED connected to GPIO 2 should be turned ON.
The code to parse the input is as follows:

```
  int numArgs = server.args();
  Serial.print("Number of args: ");
  Serial.println(numArgs);
  for (int i=0; i< numArgs; i++){
    Serial.print(server.argName(i));
    Serial.print(" : ");
    Serial.println(server.arg(i));
  }
```

Most of the URL parsing is already done by the library. Once you have the variables, your code can take suitable action.